# IE 11 Vs Sitecore 6.6 compatibility issue: Left pane is missing in sitecore content editor

Tags: internet-explorer, sitecore, internet-explorer-11, sitecore6

Sitecore content editor is not showing up any images like save, edit and left tree pane is missing in IE11 windows server. I tried adding it in compatibility mode, then the menus are displaying vertically with the images but not displaying the left pane still.

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue in a repro?

Comment: Try the recommended browser settings found in http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/browser_configuration_reference-usletter.pdf

Comment: Which version exactly you use? 6.6 rev? Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 is supported by Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev. 140410 (6.6.0 Service Pack-2) and later CMS 6.6 versions

Comment: @MarekMusielak I am using Microsoft Internet 11, Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 131211), Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11 is supported only by Sitecore 6.6.0 rev. 140410 (6.6.0 Service Pack-2) and later versions.

See official Sitecore information on [Internet Explorer 11 support article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/324411).

According to your comment, you use Sitecore 6.6.0 (rev. 131211) which does not support Internet Explorer 11.

Full information about supported browsers can be found in [Sitecore Compatibility Tables](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164).